# Find match between first vertical bars (|)

Tags: regex, google-analytics

In Google Analytics I want to filter with regex all urls where the first occurrence between vertical stripes/bars are 1 = |1|.

I searched for similar question on stackoverflow and did some tests in a regex tester. But not the result I wanted.

I tested, but it is not testing the first value between the first vertical bars.

```
\|([1]{1})\|
```

INPUT

```
https://www.website.be/results-?e=elec&Form=Home&i2=3-N-H4.225.4|1|2-Y-------Y-----1-1|1|1|1-||||0!A!A!n|0!A!A|||||||undefined!undefined-4|13-0
https://www.website.be/results-?e=elec&Form=Home&i2=3-N-H4.225.4|2|2-Y-------Y-----1-1|2|1|1-||||0!A!A!n|0!A!A|||||||undefined!undefined-4|13-0
https://www.website.be/results-?e=elec&Form=Home&i2=3-N-H4.225.4|abc|2-Y-------Y-----1-1|2|1|1-||||0!A!A!n|0!A!A|||||||undefined!undefined-4|13-0
```

Result I want

```
https://www.website.be/results-?e=elec&Form=Home&i2=3-N-H4.225.4|1|2-Y-------Y-----1-1|1|1|1-||||0!A!A!n|0!A!A|||||||undefined!undefined-4|13-0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex might be enough:

```
^[^|]*\|1\|.*$
```

### Demo

This would match all rows where the second pipe-delimited component has just the number 1.  If you also want to assert something more specific, e.g. that there are exactly 19 components, then we can try extending the pattern?:

```
^[^|]*\|1\|(?:[^|]*\|){16}[^|]*$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
result = inputs.filter(string => {
    let i = string.indexOf("|");
    return string.charAt(i+1) == "1" && string.charAt(i+2) == "|"
});
```